# Open a outlook new mail using php and html

Tags: php, html, drupal, outlook

I am creating a html page and I have a button in my html page. Once the button is clicked the outlook has to be opened with the "**To**" and the "**Subject**" information as shown in the figure.

[image]

Can any help me how to open the outlook with php.Thanks in advance.

Comment: What will you do if the client does not have outlook on his PC? the HTML commande is `<mailto ....>`

Answer (score 23, accepted):

here the link to use:

```
<a href="mailto:manish@simplygraphix.com?subject=Feedback for webdevelopersnotes.com&body=The Tips and Tricks section is great">Send me an email</a>
```

[Source is here](http://www.webdevelopersnotes.com/tips/html/html_mailto_attribute_html_tips.php3).

Comment: how to do this with a button.the outlook should open when a button is clicked.Sorry for asking simple doubts

Comment: if you use jQuery just add `$('a').button()` in the `$(document).ready()` function

Answer (score 6):

Use mailto hyperlink to open mail application on client machine

```
<a href="mailto:toid@example.com?Subject=subject here&Body=bodytext">
    Link display text
</a>
```

You can also add **cc** and **bcc** using querystring paramters as we have done for **body**.

This will open default mail application configured on client machine; It may open different application accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use a tag like following

```
<a href="mailto:your_mail@example.com">your_email</a>
```

But open Outlook, Thunderbird or other client is user's default setting.

Comment: Hi @noctilux this code is working for me, I have added this code, so that my current outlook page opening. if in case there is no outlook in the pc what will be opened please tell me , Thanks.