# how to create a html button that opens outlook application?

Tags: php, html, css

How to create a button in webpage that opens outlook application with compose mail (new mail) option attached with that webpage's screeshot?

Comment: i dont know how to add screenshot to mail but for opening outlook use this, `<a href="mailto:mail@mail.com"></a>`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Open a outlook new mail using php and html](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8503699/open-a-outlook-new-mail-using-php-and-html)

Answer (score 14):

You can simply achieve this with a single html line of code.

```
<a href="mailto:someone@something.com?subject=your title&body=TThe message">
    <button id="btnOutlook">Go to Outlook</button>
</a>
```

This can also be exted to include other fields such as

```
<a href="mailto:address..?subject=subject...&body=anything...&cc=ccemailaddress@something.com&bcc=bcc@something.com">
    <button id="btnOutlook">...</button>
</a>
```

This is a handy method to add a link to let the user contact you without the need of any server-side programming languages.

But also note that Mailto works **ONLY** if the visitor has configured an email client (such as Outlook Express) on their system.

In order to attach screenshots as you require, it's advisable to seek a solution as described [here](http://apps.devryeducationgroup.com/brandguidelines/devryuniversity/email-templates.htm).

Or the following method using Javascript and HTML5 can also be used

- In the HTML file- define markup and scripting

  ```
  <html>
  <head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="html2canvas.js"></script>
  <script>
      function take_screenshot()
      {
          html2canvas(document.body, { onrendered: function(canvas)  
          {
              var img = canvas.toDataURL()
              $.post("save_screenshot.php", {data: img}, functio(file){            
                   window.location.href =  "save_screenshot.php?file="+ file
              });
          }
          });
       }
  </script>
  <body>
       <div id="wrapper">
           <div id="screenshot_div">
               <button type="button" onclick="take_screenshot()">buttonText</button>
           </div>
       </div>
   </body>
  ```
- Make a PHP file to save the screenshot

  ```
  <?php
  if($_GET['file'])
  {
      $file=$_GET['file'];
      if (file_exists($file))
      {
          header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
          header('Content-Type: image/png');
          header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
          header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
          header('Expires: 0');
          header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
          header('Pragma: public');
          header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
          ob_clean();
          flush();
          readfile($file);
          unlink($file);
          exit;
      }
  }

  if($_POST['data'])
  {
      $data = $_POST['data'];
      $file = md5(uniqid()) . '.png';
      $uri =  substr($data,strpos($data,",")+1);
      file_put_contents('./'.$file, base64_decode($uri));
      echo $file;
      exit();
  }
  ?>
  ```

Since am not sure of your exact program structure, use this only as a guide. To attach the stored image, use the method to attach images, that I've mentioned above. For more info in this regard you can refer to [this](http://talkerscode.com/webtricks/take-screenshot-of-a-webpage-using-html5-and-javascript.php).

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you Tara, I dont want any mail id to be pre-attached in the "to:" field. All  that I want is to create a button that can open a new outlook mail with a attached screen shot of that webpage.

Comment: In this case, do you select the attachment prior to opening the mailing application(i.e  before clicking on the button)? or is it an autoshot that you expect to be attached?

Comment: No, I actually dont select. I want the screenshot to be taken and attached with that new mail with blank "to:" field

Comment: `With blank to: field` ? So does the user enter his/her desired `to:` address once they are redirected to the mailer?

Comment: In order to get a screen shot of the webpage, you'll need to incorporate Javascript as well. I've added the rest of the details to my answer above.

Comment: Thank you so much, it was very helpful. I will check the code and alter mine.

Comment: Glad I could help. Good luck!

Comment: After this I would like to add this screen shot in the "body" of my mail. How to do that?
and where did the screen shot get saved?

Comment: In the php segment, there are 2 `if conditions` with the 1st used to download the saved screenshot and the 2nd to save the screenshot. In the 2nd if condition, we get the image data sent by `take_screenshot()` function and then we save the image in the directory .In the 1st condition we first check if the file exists and if yes then we insert all the necessary header required to download the file.

Comment: So One solution is for you is that you have to manually attach the downloaded/ saved screenshot using the ***attach documents to the body*** method that I've referred in the answer. Sorry but am not very familiar with directly attaching images in the body of an email via these scripts.

Comment: You have tried to your best to make me understand. Thank you. I will try to sort out the remaining problem.

Comment: That code you sent for taking screenshot is not working. It is not taking screenshot.

Comment: I have developed a new code which takes screenshot and saves it as an image.
Now can you please tell me how to attach it to an outlook mail?

Comment: Since you have a saved image, you can use a [Base64 encoder](https://sendgrid.com/blog/embedding-images-emails-facts/) to convert your image into Base64 string. Then try embedding the image's Base64 string with an `<img alt="My Image" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4S/+RXhpZgAATU0AKgAAAAgACAESAAMAENkDZ5u8/61a+X...more encoding" />` tag within the `body` section of the `href` tag with the mailto clause.

Comment: **Example**: `<a href="mailto:someone@something.com?subject=your title&body= <img alt="My Image" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4S/+RXhpZgAATU0AKgAAAAgACAES‌​AAMAENkDZ5u8/61a+X..‌​.more encoding" />">
    <button id="btnOutlook">Go to Outlook</button>
</a>` . Let me know if this works.

Comment: Now, I have the encoded image with me but the image is not getting pasted in the body of the mail. I think the syntax you sent

Comment: The syntax you sent `<img alt="My Image" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,MY ENCODED IMAGE"/>">` is wrong

Comment: Just now I came though few pages and found that we cant attach an image to a body with `mailto`, it is only limited for text and not for html. So, we should probably go for `php`.

Answer (score 9):

You can use mailto link as explained below

Mailto link is a type of HTML link that activates the default mail client on the computer for sending an e-mail.
The web browser requires a default e-mail client software installed on his computer in order to activate the e-mail client.
If you have Microsoft Outlook, for example as your default mail client, pressing a mailto link will open a new mail window.

```
<a href="mailto:vinoth@email.com">Send Mail</a>
```

If you want to add this to button you can try below html

```
<button onclick="location.href='mailto:vinoth@email.com';">Send Mail</button>
```

Regarding your second requirement to take screenshot and attach it with mail, please refer below link, I think its answered

[How to screenshot website in JavaScript client-side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4912092/using-html5-canvas-javascript-to-take-screenshots/6678156#6678156)

Comment: Thanks but i know this option. I want to know how to add this to a button and also to attach a screenshot

Comment: I have provided a link related to screenshot issue. Hope it helps !!

Comment: Im not talking about client side here. I just want to take the screen shot my own browser screen and attach it to the new mail.